# Can "once" modify the conjunctional clause?

Tags: modifiers

> **Once when I was six** I saw a magnificent picture in a book about the
> jungle, called True Stories.

It's from "the Little Prince".

If "once" and "when I was six" are separate things, it sounds awkward. See "I saw a picture once, when I was six".

So I think "once" modifies "when I was six". See "I saw a picture, once when I was six".

It reminds me "early in the morning" in which "early" modifies "in the morning".

Can "once" modify the conjunctional clause?

Comment: Where did you find the term "conjunctional clause"?

Comment: @BillJ I made it.

Comment: @BillJ Does "early" in "early in the morning" modify "in the morning"?

Comment: Not a good idea to invent grammatical terms that make no sense!

Comment: @BillJ Sorry too much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really, the sentence would be clearer with commas:

```
"Once, when I was six, I saw a magnificent picture."
```

Break that into two different sentences:

```
"Once, I saw a magnificent picture."

"When I was six, I saw a magnificent picture."
```

The phrase "when I was six," is used in [apposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apposition), providing additional information.

"Once" does *not* modify the phrase; rather, there are two separate pieces of information:

- "Once," used in the sense of an event at an *indefinite* time in the past, and
- "When I was six," giving an idea of *when* it occurred.

Comment: Thank you, but "early" and "in the morning" in "early in the morning" are separate likewise? Not modifying?

Comment: Yes. Think, "early, in he morning," where "in the morning," is in apposition, adding info -- one might think of that phrase as modifying *earl*. Some more examples: "John, Marsha's friend," "It's heavy, over 20 kg."